# Julia pmap- writing to array

Tags: arrays, julia, pmap

Can you please point me to a code using pmap that iterates over columns of an array writing to it complex structures that are not bit type objects?
I understand that SharedArray has the limitation of requiring bit-type elements.

Thanks,

Comment: I guess your two questions should be combined into one regarding on how to share non bit-type objects between worker processes.

Answer (score 1):

A `SharedArray` is just a block of memory shared by all processes running on the same local node within a Julia cluster.
Since you share memory you need to know the size of its block and hence the requirement for the bit type.

I can think of two options:

- use a library designed for sending objects between workers in a Julia cluster - `ParallelDataTransfer.jl` does this job quite well
- try to serialize the shared object into memory using the `SharedArray` based on bytes. In this case you will need unfortunately to manage yourself the memory layout of the object.

For the second example the code could look something like this:

```
using Distributed
addprocs(2)
@everywhere using Serialization, SharedArrays
s = SharedVector{UInt8}(1_000_0000);
@everywhere struct Dat           
       a::Int                           
       b::String                        
end                                      
d = Dat(3,"hello")
```

Now this object can be written to the shared memory:

```
io = IOBuffer(s,write=true)
serialize(io, d)
```

And it can be read by remote workers:

```
julia> @sync @distributed for i in 1:2
           io = IOBuffer(s)
           dat2 = deserialize(io)
           println(myid, dat2)
       end
      From worker 2:    myidDat(3, "hello")
      From worker 3:    myidDat(3, "hello")
Task (done) @0x0000000078079140
```